# Idle animation camera Aframe

Tags: javascript, html, aframe

I'm using aframe 0.8.2 and I'm trying to add a camera idle animation (only for the rotation component). I've done this so far :

HTML:

```
<!-- Camera-->
<a-entity id = "my_c" position="8.435 0 -3.579" > <a-camera></a-camera></a-entity>
```

Javascript :

```
var scene = document.getElementById("my_s");
var camera = document.getElementById("my_c"); 
var anime_1 = document.createElement("a-animation"); 

/* Add a time of "not moving" */

    var t;
    window.onload = resetTimer;
    // DOM Events
    document.onkeypress = resetTimer;
    document.onmousedown = resetTimer;


    function standby() {
        console.log("Start standby.");
        anime_1.setAttribute("attribute","rotation");


        console.log(camera.getAttribute("rotation"));
        anime_1.setAttribute("dur", "80000");
        anime_1.setAttribute("to", "0 360 0");
        anime_1.setAttribute("easing", "linear");
        anime_1.setAttribute("repeat", "indefinite");
        camera.appendChild(anime_1);
    }

    function resetTimer() {
        clearTimeout(t);
        t = setTimeout(standby, 3000);

        camera.removeChild(anime_1);

        // 1000 milisec = 1 sec
    }
```

The problem is, I think that my camera does not upload its position and rotation : when I do rotate my camera, the camera idle animation does not start at the same position.

Thanks for your support :)

Answer (score 0):

You could handle the `from` and `to` properties differently:

```
...
let initCamRotation = camera.getAttribute("rotation")
let endCamRotation = initCameraRotation
endCamRotation.y += 360
anime_1.setAttribute("from", initCamRotation);
anime_1.setAttribute("to", endCamRotation);
....
```

---

A bit offtop, but the [animation component](https://github.com/ngokevin/kframe/tree/master/components/animation)s animation can be paused when given `pauseEvents`, i'd try using it instead of the `a-animation` entity. Here im not sure if you can interrupt the animation while it started.

Comment: I 'm trying to do it with the animation component. I'll answer you later today ^^ Thank you